# python selenium cant find iframe xpath

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, xpath

I am having an issue with Selenium and not being able to switch to a frame. I have tried using the xpath of iframe but it replies that the element was not found. This was the code I was using:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="VF"]'))
```

I have also tried using a css-selector but it gives me the same result. I suspect that the div element that holds the iframe that I want to select is causing this issue but I'm not sure. Here's what that div element looks like:

```
<div id="dee_0" class="ar BAResults" fframe='<iframe title="SRC" src="javascript:&quot;&lt;HTML&gt;&lt;/HTML&gt;&quot;" onload="DVFol&#40;&#41;"></iframe>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit
this is the iframe I'm trying to target

```
<iframe name="VF" title="SRC" id="VF" src='javascript:"<HTML></HTML>"' frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 830px; height: 490px; background-color: transparent;" allowtransparency="true" onload="F(0,302899400).ol()">
```

stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kthao.ISC/PycharmProjects/AutoComplete/test2.py", line 32, in 
<module>
chrome.switch_to_frame(chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="VF"]'))
File "C:\Users\kthao.ISC\Desktop\AutoComplete\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 368, in 
find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "C:\Users\kthao.ISC\Desktop\AutoComplete\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 858, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\kthao.ISC\Desktop\AutoComplete\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\kthao.ISC\Desktop\AutoComplete\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*
[@id="VF"]"}
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: We are not seeing //[@id="VF"] anywhere in your html code

Comment: I just added the stack trace and the iframe I'm targeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to switch to an `iframe` is **`switch_to.frame()`** and the `<iframe>` tag contains the attribute `title` as **`SRC`**. So you can use the following line of code :

```
 driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='SRC']"))
```

Comment: this did work but i had to use
`driver.switch_to_default_content()`
the only way i figure this out is to print all the code within the frame.