# unable to locate iframe with xpath and id in python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, iframe

I have been trying to click an accept button in an `iframe`, but I am unable to locate this `iframe` with `xpath`. I have checked similar SO posts but to no avail.

[Selenium can't locate iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576206/selenium-cant-locate-iframe), [python selenium cant find iframe xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898340/python-selenium-cant-find-iframe-xpath)

[This is the HTML of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEW5V.png)

I have tried following so far.

`wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"pop-frame028142186741537767")))` gives `TimeoutException`.

Also tried:

`time.sleep(10)`
`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='truste_box_overlay']/div[@class='truste_box_overlay_inner']/iframe[@id='pop-frame028142186741537767']"))`

Error

`NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='truste_box_overlay']/div[@class='truste_box_overlay_inner']/iframe[@id='pop-frame028142186741537767']`

Finding the the `iframe` `driver.find_elements_by_id('pop-frame028142186741537767')` gives an empty list. However, I am able to locate two parent `div` elements with `xpath` and `class` attributes.

**EDIT**:
`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('truste_box_overlay')` gives outermost `div` element. But, accessing same element with `id` 
`driver.find_elements_by_id('pop-div20738421000570183')` gives empty list.

So, I suppose `find_elements_by_id` not working?! How can I go about to solve this problem? I am not able to progress as without clicking this button I can't interact to the main content.

Comment: If you have just 1 iframe on the site, then you can locate it by tag name.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov I am afraid locating by tag name will not work. There are a number of iframes.

Comment: Is this "pop-frame028142186741537767" static? If you're trying to find by ID and the ID is not static that might be your problem. You can find by XPath using partial search //iframe[contains(@id, 'pop-frame')]

Comment: @ratsstack The partial search actually solves the problem. I was stupidly inspecting the same page opened first time for hours and did not check subsequent instances in experiments. It never crossed my mind that ID could be dynamic in this case. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Great to hear. I have posted this as an answer. Would appreciate if you would accept it so I can build some reputation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching by an ID which is auto-generated and will not work the next time the page is reloaded. Instead try XPath using partial search //iframe[contains(@id, 'pop-frame')]

Answer (score 0):

Switch back to the default content (out of the ):

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.switch_to.frame("iframe name")

driver.find_elements_by_class_name('truste_box_overlay')
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I am able to find `div` element with `truste_box_overlay` as class name. But, as I mentioned, I am unable to locate `iframe` by id (there is no `name` attribute). I get `NoSuchFrameException: pop-frame028142186741537767`. I didn't get the purpose of `driver.switch_to.default_content()` at the start when we are already interacting with main page. Still, I tried it, but it doesn't work.